# Plotly sorting dataset

Tags: javascript, sorting, plotly

I havent been able to find any documentation about this so i am hoping that one of you guys might be able to help.

I have the following chart options:

```
var charData = [{
        x: x,
        y: y,
        type: 'bar',
        marker: {
            color: '#3BBFB9'
        },
        name: $filter('translate')('COMPETENCES.GRAPH.CURRENT')
    }],
    layout = {
        legend: {
            traceorder: 'reversed'
        },
        margin:{
            b: 200
        }
    };
```

Where `x` is a list of names and `y` looks like this:

```
[1, 13, 13, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 15, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Now i wish to add a sort functionality where my users can press it and the chart sorts (from low to high)

However im not sure how to do this. The `plotly` documentation doesnt state anything about sorting its data.

Note if i can just set it in the `chartData configuration` that it sorts low to high that would be very helpful aswell!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the solution but here is what I did.
Create custom legends which are your sorting options and upon clicking those legends call a function to sort the x-axis or y-axis data. To refresh the chart, add your `charData` variable in a function and call it with new x-axis and y-axis values.